# How to print the output of each EC2 instance of a run command executed through SSM automation document

Tags: powershell, aws-ssm, aws-powershell

I am trying to print the output of **multiple EC2 instances** executed **via AWS-RunPowerShellScript document through AWS SSM Automation**in Automation execution step outputs section. However, it seems to be not working. Can anyone help me with correct syntax for the same. Please find the below code:

```
description: printssmruncommandoutput
schemaVersion: '0.3'
mainsteps:
  -name:printssmoutput
   action:'aws:runcommand'
   onfailure:Abort
   inputs:
     DocumentName:AWS-RunPowerShellScript
     Targets:
       -Key: ec2key
        Values:
          - ec2instance
     Parameters:
       Commands:
         - 'hostname'
         - 'Write-Host "this is the test server"'
   outputs:
     - Name: DesiredOutput
       Selector: $.OutputPayload
       Type: String

outputs:
 - DesiredOutput.OutputPayload.CommandId
 - DesiredOutput.OutputPayload.Status
```

It seems like not working. In the outputs section of SSM Automation execution, I am seeing this error even after successful execution of SSM automation document step: **"No output available yet because the step is not successfully executed"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question and finally figured it out.  I have not been able to access `OutputPayload` as a JSON object but you can access the four items it contains: `Status`, `ResponseCode`, `Output`, and `CommandId`.

```
description: PrintSSMRunCommandOutput
schemaVersion: "0.3"
mainSteps:
  - name: PrintSSMOutput
    action: aws:runCommand
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
      DocumentName: AWS-RunPowerShellScript
      Targets:
        - Key: tag:ec2key
          Values:
            - ec2instance
      Parameters:
        commands:
          - hostname
          - Write-Host "this is the test server"
    outputs:
      - Name: OutputStatus
        Selector: $.Status
        Type: String
      - Name: OutputResponseCode
        Selector: $.ResponseCode
        Type: Integer
      - Name: OutputOutput
        Selector: $.Output
        Type: String
      - Name: OutputCommandId
        Selector: $.CommandId
        Type: String
outputs:
  - PrintSSMOutput.OutputStatus
  - PrintSSMOutput.OutputResponseCode
  - PrintSSMOutput.OutputOutput
  - PrintSSMOutput.OutputCommandId
```